# Python object property type conversion without creating new instance of an object

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm looking for a way to convert Python object property type or cast it without creating new instance of an object. Consider the following code:

```
import enum
import requests

class HttpHeaders(str, enum.Enum):
    forwarded_for = 'X-Forwarded-For'
    content_type = 'Content-Type'

myheaders = {
    HttpHeaders.forwarded_for: "192.168.0.1",
    HttpHeaders.content_type: "text/porn",
}

# The line below is needed for requests >= 2.28.0
myheaders= {xkey.value: xval for xkey, xval in myheaders.items() }
requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000', "zima", headers=myheaders)
```

Python requests library starting from version 2.28.0 introduced strict type checking of http headers which is  vaguely mentioned in the [release notes](https://github.com/psf/requests/blame/main/HISTORY.md#L34-L35), so the code above without the line:

```
myheaders= {xkey.value: xval for xkey, xval in myheaders.items() }
```

is going to throw exception:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader: Header part (<HttpHeaders.content_encoding: 'X-Content-Encoding'>) from {<HttpHeaders.content_encoding: 'X-Content-Encoding'>: 'gzip'} must be of type str or bytes, not <enum 'HttpHeaders'>
```

Unfortunately this fix creates new instance of an object which incurs performance penalty (in case of a small array it's meaningless but still doesn't look like a great fix).

What would be the recommended fix for that?

Comment: You could just add `.value` to the keys in your original declaration, couldn’t you?  I don’t understand the point of doing it in two steps in the first place, except as a quick and dirty way of fixing compatibility with old code.  Not only is it slower at runtime, it’s harder to read, and it also breaks static typechecking since the type of `myheaders` isn’t consistent.

Comment: Starting with 3.11, the `StrEnum` type may solve the problem.

Comment: @Samwise It is indeed a quick and dirty way of fixing compatibility with the old code. Thanks for the suggestion. It's a good one but still this way I'm changing the original object that might be needed in it's original form in a different place and I would prefer to preserve it in the original form and still be able to use new requests without creating new instance of an object. Is that possible at all?

Comment: Given the size of these objects, I don't think it's worth worrying about.

Comment: The time it takes to actually *complete* the request is going to dwarf the time it takes to define the headers properly.

Comment: BTW link to the issue on github related to this change: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6159